# Get Front end of Access DB to work across multiple users without mapped network drives

Tags: microsoft-access

Is there a way to get front end of the Access DB to work across multiple users without mapped network drives?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I know for this would be to connect your front-end to a SQL database.

That allows each user to have his own front-end and each one will connect to your central SQL database.

Microsoft has a [webpage on the different ways to share access databases](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ways-to-share-an-access-desktop-database-03822632-da43-4d8f-ba2a-68da245a0446).

Comment: UNC paths are valid and recommended as your link to docs shows;)